# FBA with AD provider and Windows Authentication not the same user?

Tags: active-directory, authentication, forms-authentication, membership-provider

is there a way that my FBA (ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider) logged user like jo@xxx.com and the Windows Authentication user jo@xxx.com became the same user (meaning they have the same user id) and share the same item in the user information list and the same profile ?

I think they are treated as two differents user.

Any help apreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010, you could normalize the accounts by creating/configuring a TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer that generates the same identity claim regardless of the authentication method.

Comment: So I cannot use ActiveDirectoryMembership FBA and Windows Authentitcation to be identified as the same AD user and have the samed userid in SP ?

Comment: You cannot. Since the authentication provider is different, SharePoint considers it two different user accounts.